# Closing file problem when opening FoxitReader with TexnicCenter

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, viewers

I use the FoxitReader instead of Acrobat Reader to see the pdf files. I defined it when I installed  TeXnicCenter. When a new file is compiled, it does not automatically closes off the old one. So in order to see the new file, I have to manually close the old file in Foxit Reader (click the X). What can I do? 
Should I change "Close document before running Latex: Do not close"? If so, with what?
Related: http://consult.wikidot.com/latex#foxit

The project's options are:

```
Profile Latex:  
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe  
-interaction=nonstopmode "%pm"  
Bibtex:  
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\bibtex.exe  
"%bm"  
Makeindex:  
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe  
"%bm"  

Under Viewer:  
Path C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\FOXIT SOFTWARE\FOXIT READER\FOXIT READER.EX  
View Project's Output  Command line: "%bm.pdf"  
Close document before running Latex: Do not close
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you rather use [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) as a PDF viewer. You do not need to close it before recompiling your document and (very important) it has SyncTex capabilities. That means that you can jump direct from a position in the viewer to the corresponding text in your Latex file and vice versa.

The following setup is from the [TeXnicCenter tutorials](http://www.texniccenter.org/resources/tutorials).

---

Change the existing profile `LaTeX=>PDF` or make a copy say, `LaTeX=>PDF (Sumatra)`. Edit the profile. Under the three tabs: *(La)Tex*, *Postprocessor* and
*Viewer* make the following settings:

**(La)Tex:**
Command line arguments to pass to the compiler

```
-synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%Wm"
```

**Postprocessor:**
No settings required

**Viewer:**
Path of executable

```
"<path>\SumatraPDF.exe" -inverse-search "\"<path>\TEXCNTR.EXE\" /ddecmd \"[goto(’%f’,’%l’)]\""
```

At View project's output set the radio button to `Command line argument`

- Command: `"%bm.pdf"`

At Forward search set the radiobutton to `DDE Command`

- Command: `[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]`
- Server: `SUMATRA`
- Topic: `Control`

At Close document before running (La)TeX set the radio button to `Do not close`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Says "I can't write on file 'output.pdf'. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem (see for example 
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=170598 )

Some work-around, not perfect but the best available (in Windows 7)

Use the **batch file:**

TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %2.pdf*"
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" %1

Note: Windows 7 does not have the command kill

-A typical file looks like name.pdf-Foxit Reader[name.pdf]
%2 is the second parameter (given by %tm)
eq means equal
so %2.pdf* kills the processes with window title having the %tm extension
the processes can be seen with tasklist

**Path of executable**
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\batch.bat"
View project's output
command line
 "%bm.pdf" %tm
Forward Search: blank command line
Close document: do not close

And if you have different pdf files use **multiple instances** in the Foxit Reader tools-->preferences
Different instances have different processes(PID)